# React rerenders whole component when its properties change

Tags: reactjs

Let's consider the following sample:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class B extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(`Render runs with ${this.props.paramA}`);
    return (<div>{this.props.paramA}</div> );
  }
}

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {paramA: 'asd'};
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({paramA: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <input value={this.state.paramA} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
      <label>
      <B paramA={this.state.paramA}></B>
      </label>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

[Here's the gif](https://static.pychat.org/photo/AXaiM0zU_Tue_Sep_12_234258_2017.gif) of how it works.

If you noted, in order to update the changes from properties, react needs to evaluate "render" method. That causes the whole component to update  instead of its small part that really changed (check the gif, the div element blinks in chrome developer tools):

**TL;DR** According to react philosophy,apps should be written in a way to have as many [dummy](https://jaketrent.com/post/smart-dumb-components-react/) components as possible. That means we have to pass properties a few level down sometimes (other time we can use e.g. redux), which leads to a lot of `render` methods that evaluate every time the property of top level component changes. With all that being said I often see in the real life react application that a whole `root` div blinks when e.g. users types something into input. Well even if it's a browser "lag" I don't really like the idea that react reevaluates all components (meaning running their render method) when a component needs to update only its small part.

**The question**:
Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to implement react component so they update only things that changed?

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting what the blink means in the chrome devtools; it doesn't necessarily mean that the div is being destroyed and recreated; manually modifying the `innerText` of an element in the JS console produces the same effect

Comment: @Hamms ok that was a bad example, I will provide another one soon with an edit, but the point remains the same, react does update the whole component (not always tho, I mean some `if` statements of loops will do the trick).

Comment: It depends on what exactly you mean by "update"; React does [quite a bit of clever reconciliation work](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) to try and ensure that it only touches the DOM itself when it's absolutely necessary. This means that, yes, a lot of `render` calls are happening but they're not as actually expensive as you might think they are

Comment: Note that one very common approach to more-selective updates is to use something like [redux](http://redux.js.org/) to manage your state rather than passing changes through a bunch of intermediate components

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle hook.

Pretty self explanatory;  if the component should only re-render under specific prop/state changes, you can specify those in this hook, and return false otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I know about it. First of all I want to say that people are lazy, I mean would you drink a cup of tee at your work or implement some hook and put logic there, that does absolutely nothing but saves some performance? I guess framework should take care of that. Well second, in the example above component should always update when its property changes, but it needs to update only the `text` part, not the whole div!

Comment: I honestly think you're over-engineering and finding problems where they don't exist.  React is *obscenely* fast at managing the render lifecycles, and compares primitives in the props/state as well as caches results from render methods to optimize itself.  If you do really want to enforce something app-wide, you could use immutable.js to allow react to faster compare old/new props and re-use past renders more often.  But even that is likely overkill.

Comment: I would argue with that one. Check this out, I'm just holding down `D` key on input. `<input onChange` just triggers reevaluating "render" method that has only a hundred lines. 
Note how it lags. https://static.pychat.org/photo/p9hSJSV7_Wed_Sep_13_174200_2017.gif

Comment: Looks like material-ui?  I've seen that problem with their library before, but I think it's a result of something specific to those components, not react-wide.  In the past, I solved the issue on their library by adding the [`pure-render-mixin`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, React is not rerendering the entire component but the first parent of the dynamic part of them. In this case, the `<div>` is the parent (and the entire component so you're right), but in this fiddle wrapping `{this.props.paramA}` inside a paragraph tag, the `<div>` is not the direct parent, so just rerenders `<p>` tag and `<div>` does not need to update.

```js
class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(`Render runs with ${this.props.paramA}`);
    return (<div><p>{this.props.paramA}</p></div> );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {paramA: 'asd'};
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({paramA: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <input value={this.state.paramA} onChange={e => this.handleChange.bind(this)(e)}/>
      <label>
      <B paramA={this.state.paramA} />
      </label>
    </div>);
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Here's another the example I'm talking about. I will try to minimize it and provide a code base soon. https://static.pychat.org/photo/0NBV84EB_Wed_Sep_13_011022_2017.gif